# flutter 'System UI isn't responding' crashing after installing firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm getting the 'System UI isn't responding' message every time I launch my app & periodically whilst using it even though the app is working fine.

I installed firebase_core and firebase_firestore and since then i've been having these issues and I'm not sure why.

potentially related dependencies and versions:

```
 http: 0.12.2
 get: ^4.1.4
 get_storage: ^2.0.2
 firebase_core: ^0.7.0
 cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0
```

I'm getting these errors in the console (I'm also using `GetX` which is why there is some logging for it)

```
Restarted application in 1,184ms.
W/DynamiteModule(10246): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule(10246): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(10246): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler(10246): callback not found for CALLBACK_AVAILABLE message
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been initialized
[GETX] Instance "AuthController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "AuthController" has been initialized
I/flutter (10246): null
[GETX] REPLACE ROUTE null
[GETX] NEW ROUTE null
F/crash_dump32(12592): crash_dump.cpp:474] failed to attach to thread 180: Permission denied
```

I've added these to my `gradle.properties`

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

I've also added v to my `AndroidManifest` as was suggested in another question

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I've ensured that I've done the firebase setup correctly. The only other thing I could think of is my http version, I had to downgrade it to work with the firebase dependencies.

This is the error: https://chumberjosh-websites.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/gainzzz-error.png

Comment: Have you added your google services-json file in your project?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the emulator I was using was running android api 30, when I changed it to 29 it worked